# React funtion components store variable like a class member

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm quite new to react and I'm making a project. I need to a global hold a variable and update it ONCE when the component is created.

This object needs to be something like a hash map. Something like this:

```js
const startState = [];
const comp = (props) => {
   const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState({ id: "123" });
   ...
   //someVar is updated to a propper id
   
   somethingLikeAConstructor( () => {
      addToStartState( { someVar.id: {width: "123"} } );
   } );
   
};
```

This variable should store the initial state of all the created components on something like a hash map(So I can associate the corresponding components to right width values ) and it should be available to the other parts of the program.

But the width values are updated inside the component, I do not want the array to be updated when the values of the component is changed, I just want to store the starting values of each created component.

There needs to be only one variable that gets updated once when a component is created and it should be accessable globally.

So it must be something like a traditional class variable like in other OOP languages.

On another language I would do it like this:

```
class someClass{
public:
    static startValues = []
    constructor()
    {
       ... // calculate the width
       startValues.append(this.width);
    }
};
```

How can I achieve this effect on function components? And what type of variable I should use to get that id association effect?

Comment: See [How do lifecycle methods correspond to hooks?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-lifecycle-methods-correspond-to-hooks) and [How to avoid passing callbacks down?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down) and [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lessons-learned)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said you want to have a global and have it updated each time a component is *first mounted*.

There are at least two ways to do that:

- [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)
- [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

`useEffect` is the usual solution and probably the one you want.

### `useEffect`

When you use `useEffect` with an empty dependency array, it calls its callback when the component is mounted but not on subsequent re-renders:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ...write to your global here...
}, []);
```

If you need to do something when the component is *un*mounted, you can return a callback to do that:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ...write to your global here...
    return () => {
        // ...write your cleanup code here...
    };
}, []);
```

**But**, note that the `useEffect` callback is called *just after* the component is rendered and committed to the DOM, not before. Most of the time, this is what you want. In your case you've referred to element widths, so you'd be using refs to those elements, and those won't be filled in until the component is rendered and committed.

### `useRef`

**If** you have an unusual situation where you need to do something the first time is a component is mounted **before** it's rendered and committed, you can do that with a ref via `useRef`:

```
const mountedRef = useRef(false);
if (!mountedRef.current) {
    mountedRef.current = true;
    // ...write to your global here...
}
```

There's no equivalent of the cleanup callback, but you can combine the `useRef` with the `useEffect` to get cleanup:

```
const mountedRef = useRef(false);
if (!mountedRef.current) {
    mountedRef.current = true;
    // ...write to your global here...
}
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        // ...do your cleanup here...
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: @Crowder The thing is I want one global variable, but every component should update that global variable once when they are initialized. I guess I wrote the question a bit poorly, I'll fix it.

Comment: @Turgut - Sorry, somehow I missed your comment. What is the value you want to store in the global? You've used "width" in your question, do you mean the width of the component? Or...?

Comment: @Crowder Well yes. My edit further clarifies my intents. Right now I need to store a variable globally that's all. I figured how to initialize them once like with a constructor. But now I need to reliably make that variable accessable outside of the function.

Comment: @Turgut - What if the component is unmounted? Do you leave the information in the global?

Comment: @Crowder Doesn't really matter. It's for a calculation. If i have to chose I would like it to be removed when It's unmounted but if the other way is more efficient/ has better performance I can use that too.

Comment: @Turgut - I've updated the answer. I included information about doing cleanup just in case.

Comment: @Crowder Hmm so the return value of `useEffect` acts like a destructor. I was trying to use `useRef` but appereantly I was using it wrong. Thanks!